# How do I access a private swagger API with a maven-build-plugin?

Tags: maven, swagger

I have generated an API in swagger (API 3.0.0):
Offer-Api:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
[…]
paths:
  /offers:
    get:
      summary: get all offers
      operationId: allOffers
      description: return ALL offers
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results matching criteria
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiOffer'
          links:
            GetOffererById:
              $ref: 'https://api.swaggerhub.com/apis/comp/offers/1.0.0#/components/links/GetSingleOffererById'
            GetOfferById:
              $ref: '#/components/links/GetSingleOfferById'
        '400':
          description: something went terribly wrong
[…]
```

I copied that content into my project as an „Offers.yaml“ and try to compile it via „openapi-generator-maven-plugin“

```
  […]
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          […]
          <execution>
            <id>Offers</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Offers.yaml</inputSpec>
              <modelPackage>${project.modelpackage}</modelPackage>
              <apiPackage>${project.apipackage}</apiPackage>
              <generateApis>false</generateApis>
              <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
              <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
              <generateModels>true</generateModels>
              <generateModelTests>true</generateModelTests>
              <withXml>true</withXml>
              <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <generatorName>java</generatorName>
              <library>jersey2</library>
              <validateSpec>false</validateSpec>
              <configOptions>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/</sourceFolder>
                <java8>true</java8>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    […]
```

During maven-compile following error occurs:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate (Offers) @ server --- 
[ERROR] unable to read 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.swaggerhub.com/apis/comp/offerers/1.0.0
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
```

Sure, https://api.swaggerhub.com/apis/comp/offerers/1.0.0 is a PRIVATE API. But is there a way to tell the maven plugin the correct credentials, so that it can access that API anyway?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maven, but SwaggerHub has a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swaggerhub-maven-plugin) that lets you download private definitions, maybe you could call that before the generator step? Otherwise you'll need to provide the `Authorization: YOUR-API-KEY` header somehow to authorize SwaggerHub downloads.